# Remove duplicate in python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

I have data frame like this ( shown in image). I need to remove duplicate from inside of Data frame list. can you help me.

[image: my out put]

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Show your code and the complete error message, if any.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: you could convert each list to a set (and back to a list if needed), this will remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Just building on the answer of @Sachin Kohli and the astute observation of @
Ignatius Reilly, you can use a regex to extract the datetimes and then use the same process

Here's an example dataframe similar to yours above;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date modified':['[18/3/2022 9:35:54, 18/3/2022 9:35:54]','[18/3/2022 9:35:54, 18/3/2022 9:35:54, 18/3/2022 9:35:55]']})
```

And the following code will extract the dates and remove duplicates.

```
import re
date_pattern = r'\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+'
df["Date modified1"] = df["Date modified"].apply(lambda x:list(set(re.findall(date_pattern,x))))
```

I've added a new column `Date modified1` but obviously you could also just replace the original column as well.

If ordering is important in the lists, then it's probably easiest to use a helper function.  The following adds an intermediate step of converting to datetime objects so that ordering works.

```
import re
import datetime
def helper(s):
    re_date_pattern = r'\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+'
    dt_date_pattern = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
    date_strings =  re.findall(re_date_pattern, s)
    date_times = sorted(list(set(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, dt_date_pattern), date_strings))))
    return list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, dt_date_pattern), date_times))
```

And this can be used in a similar way as the example above, but without the need for the lambda function;

```
df["Date modified1"] = df["Date modified"].apply(helper)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what @bn_ln is referring to... doable using apply-lambda function;

```
df["Date modified1"] = df["Date modified"].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Comment: 0      [/, 5, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 4, 9, 2, :]
1      [/, 5, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 4, 9, 2, :]
2      [/, 5, 1, 0,  , 3, 4, 9, 6, 2, :]
3      [/, 5, 1, 0,  , 3, 4, 9, 6, 2, :]
4            [/, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 4, 2, :]
                     ...                
259          [/, 5, 1, 0,  , 3, 4, 2, :]
260       [/, 5, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 6, 2, :]
261       [/, 5, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 6, 2, :]
262          [/, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 4, 2, :]
263          [/, 1, 0, 8,  , 3, 4, 2, :]
Name: Date modified1, Length: 264, dtype: object                                 not work. I 'm getting output like this .

Comment: That's because you don't have a list as your questions says, but strings. Show the actual data, not an image! We cannot know just looking at an image whether those are strings or lists. You can use `.to_dict()` on a subset of your dataframe and paste the output, so we can reproduce it.